# diff momentjs days vs milliseconds yields different results

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my code I have the following

```
const today = moment();
const someday = moment('Wed Oct 10 2018 13:50:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)');

const diff = today.diff(someday, "days");
const diff2 = today.diff(someday);
out.innerText = diff;
out2.innerText = moment.utc(diff2 * 1000).format("D[ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)]");
```

I am expecting diff and diff2 to have same days but diff returns correct date where as diff2 returns the incorrect data. How does formatting here make a difference?

JSFiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/89xsqohz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out2.innerText = moment.duration(diff2).asDays();
```

This will give you the decimal number of days (without the utc conversion) -- and this matches what you're seeing with `today.diff(someday, "days")`.

You could format it yourself in the desired X day(s) Y hour(s) Z minute(s) fashion like this:

```
const theDuration = moment.duration(diff2);
out2.innerText = Math.floor(theDuration.asDays()) + " day(s) " + 
  theDuration.hours() + " hour(s) " + theDuration.minutes() + " minute(s)";
```

Just make sure the time zones are all matched up between your input date format / the clock on the machine you're calculating on / the desired user output. This is a useful overview on the docs page: [local / utc](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/).

I've also seen the moment-duration-format library mentioned as useful: https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

<strike>Try:</strike>

```
out2.innerText = moment.utc(diff2).format("DDDD [ day(s)] H[ hour(s)] m[ minute(s)]");
```

Using "Day of year" (DDDD) instead of "Day of month" (DD) in the format string [(moment.js .format docs)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), and removing the unnecessary `* 1000` in the `.utc` constructor, since like Jb31 mentioned, diff2 is already in milliseconds. Per Jb31, this is a quite awful idea when the days in the diff hits 365...

Comment: Thank you. The explanation and the links were very helpful.

Comment: "DDDD" is quite dangerous for time differences > 365 days, isn't it?

Comment: @Jb31 you are 100% correct. Thank you for pointing that out! @Maddy I updated the answer to strikeout this inaccuracy & w/ info on why `.format("DDDD")` is a poor approach.

Answer (score 0):

`today.diff(someday)` returns the difference between the two days in milliseconds when no second parameter is given (like `'days'`). In `out2` you attempt to interpret this as a unix timestamp. This is wrong for two reasons:

- You don't need to multiply the difference with 1000, it's in milliseconds already.
- Even if you didn't do the multiply, the statement seems pointless as `moment.utc(diff2)` will point to 1970-10-06 (seen from today). The format command will then return the days, hours and minutes part of this date.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a little confused. How can I make sure that days returned in the format is correct?

Comment: How can I get the format to display the correct days hours and minutes?